# BATCH Script - Read XML and return multiple values for the same tag/element and pass it as variable

Tags: xml, windows, batch-file

Here is code which gives reads ONLY the last TargetEndpoint tag in the xml file and gives the output as - Facebook

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set input="TP.xml"

for /f "tokens=3 delims=<> " %%i in ('type %input% ^|find "TargetEndpoint"') do set "targetsName=%%i"
echo %targetsName%"
```

We want the ability to read all the TargetEndpoint tags and output as to pass it to a batch script as an array of variables--
Apple, Google, Microsoft, Adobe, Facebook

XML file for reference:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <Name revision="1" name="myname">
    <ConfigurationVersion majorVersion="4" minorVersion="0"/>
    <Description>myxml</Description>
    <Policies>
        <!--test1 -->
    </Policies> 
    <Resources>
         <!--test1 -->
    </Resources>
    <TargetServers/>
    <TargetEndpoints>
        <TargetEndpoint>Apple</TargetEndpoint>
        <TargetEndpoint>Google</TargetEndpoint>
        <TargetEndpoint>Microsoft</TargetEndpoint>
        <TargetEndpoint>Adobe</TargetEndpoint>
        <TargetEndpoint>Facebook</TargetEndpoint>
    </TargetEndpoints>
    <validate>false</validate>
</Name>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend parsing your XML as XML, rather than tokenizing and scraping it as text. If you parse it as XML, then the success of your script won't be so dependent upon whether the XML is beautified, uglified, minified, whatever.  Since the batch language has no easy way to interpret the XML DOM, you can borrow from Windows Script Host by using a [batch + JScript hybrid script](https://gist.github.com/davidruhmann/5199433).  Save this with a .bat extension and give it a try.

```js
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

@echo off
setlocal

set "XMLfile=test.xml"
set "nodes=TargetEndpoint"

rem // build array of text node values for TargetEndpoint nodes
set "Ubound=-1"

for /f "delims=" %%I in (
    'cscript /nologo /e:JScript "%~f0" "%XMLfile%" "%nodes%"'
) do (
    set "%%I"
    set /a Ubound += 1
)

rem // display array
set %nodes%

rem // demonstrate retrieval of a value
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
echo Last element: %nodes%[%Ubound%] = !%nodes%[%Ubound%]!
endlocal

goto :EOF
@end // end batch / begin JScript chimera

String.prototype.trim = function() { return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, ''); }

var DOM = WSH.CreateObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM'),
    args = { file: WSH.Arguments(0), node: WSH.Arguments(1) },
    XPath = "//" + args.node + "/text()";

DOM.load(args.file);
DOM.async = false;
DOM.setProperty('SelectionLanguage', 'XPath');

if (DOM.parseError.errorCode) {
    var e = DOM.parseError;
    WSH.StdErr.WriteLine('Error in ' + args.file + ' line ' + e.line + ' char '
        + e.linepos + ':\n' + e.reason + '\n' + e.srcText);
    WSH.Quit(1);
}

for (var d = DOM.selectNodes(XPath), i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
    WSH.Echo(args.node + '[' + i + ']=' + d[i].nodeValue.trim());
}
```

---

You could actually do something similar with PowerShell with a one-liner.  If the structure of your XML is static and you don't need to search via XPath, you could do something like this:

```js
powershell "[xml]$x = (gc test.xml); $x.Name.TargetEndpoints.TargetEndpoint"
```

Or if an XPath is needed to select the `TargetEndpoint` nodes:

```js
powershell "select-xml '//TargetEndpoint/text()' test.xml | %{ $_.node.data }"
```

Be advised that PowerShell's XML parser is more strict than the `Microsoft.XMLDOM` COM object.  Your example XML above would error with the PowerShell XML parser because the `<?xml?>` declaration is preceded by whitespace.  Jscript, on the other hand, doesn't seem to care.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is just a simple bracket problem. You need to group the set and the echo commands inside the loop, this will print each as it loops through. It currently only prints facebook as thats the last one it finds in the list and is what is stored in the variable once the loop has finished.

For example:

```
    @echo off
setlocal enableextensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set input="TP.xml"

for /F "tokens=3 delims=<>" %%I in ('type %input% ^|find "TargetEndpoint"') do (
    set targetendpoint=%%I
    echo !targetendpoint!
)
```