# Using "for /F" command to find specific text in xml file and use as variable in a batch file

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to find the following version number in a app.config file.
The file is XML format.

Line 8 in the file (Adding line in again as the greater/less than symbols were stripped from the post initially)

add key="ReleaseVersion" value="5.2.0.2"

I been using various FOR /F commands, have been close a couple of times.
However I have not been able to extract the 5.2.0.2 value and use as a variable
so far in my script.

Additionally while I am looking for this value 5.2.0.2, going forward the version number will change so I am not looking for a exact match e.g. "5.2.0.2", I am looking to capture what is in the inverted commas e.g. value="", and then using this as a variable in my script.

Example of what I have tried so far...

```
FOR /f "tokens=3 delims=5." %%a IN ('TYPE appsettings.config ^| FIND "ReleaseVersion"') DO SET do set word3=%%a
FOR /F delims^=^"^ tokens^=2 %%G IN ('FINDSTR /L "ReleaseVersion" "appsettings.config"')
FOR /f "tokens=3 usebackq delims== " %%G in (`appsettings.config`) do @echo %~G
```

Have tried a number of techniques but as yet, nothing has been successful. 
Can post more information as required however that essentially covers the issue.

Comment: Yikes. This calls for a real app. Batch files are somewhat limited when it comes to parsing data and such. You need something with built in string handling functions. I recommend using C++. [Visual Studio](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs.aspx) is a free IDE / compiler which you can use to create console apps.

Comment: `FOR /f "tokens=3 delims==" %%a IN ('TYPE appsettings.config ^| FIND "ReleaseVersion"') DO SET "word3=%%~a"`

Comment: You could also use powershell's `Get-Content .\rowstowrite.py | Select-String -Pattern "ReleaseVersion" | Format-Table -GroupBy Path`

Comment: Or here's a novel idea.  How about treating the XML *as* XML, rather than complicated text to hack and scrape?  [See this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31822245/1683264) for an idea or two.  There are a couple of PowerShell one-liners there that might help -- one that traverses the DOM, and another that uses an XPath selector.  Pick one, salt to taste, and capture its output with a `for /F` loop to use as a batch variable.

Answer (score 1):

Supposing the `add key="ReleaseVersion" value="5.2.0.2"` portion is in a single line and the related `value` parameter appears after the `ReleaseVersion` substring, the following could work for you:

```dos
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
rem define constants:
set "SEARCH=ReleaseVersion"
set "KEYWORD=value"
rem get line of interest and assign it to `LINE`:
for /F "delims=" %%L in ('findstr /L "%SEARCH%" "app.config"') do (
    set "LINE=%%L"
)
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem cut everything off up to the search string:
set "LINE=!LINE:*%SEARCH%=!"
rem cut everything off up to the keyword:
set "LINE=!LINE:*%KEYWORD%=!"
rem extract the version number:
for /F tokens^=1^ delims^=^"^=^/^<^>^  %%N in ("!LINE!") do (
    set "VNUM=%%N"
)
rem transfer the version number over the `setlocal`/`endlocal` barrier:
endlocal & endlocal & set "VNUM=%VNUM%"
echo ReleaseVersion: %VNUM%
exit /B
```

The string portion of interest does not need to look exactly like shown above, but may contain more or less spaces (for example `add   key = "ReleaseVersion"  value = "5.2.0.2"`), or include the `"` or not (like `add key=ReleaseVersion value=5.2.0.2`). The only condition is that the attribute `key` needs to appear before the attribute `value`.

Answer (score 0):

If the search line is precisely this one:

```
add key="ReleaseVersion" value="5.2.0.2"
```

... then this code should work:

```
@echo off
setlocal

for /F "tokens=3" %%a in ('findstr "ReleaseVersion" "appsettings.config"') do set %%a
set "value=%value:~1,-1%"
echo %value%
```

If the layout of the search line change (more blank spaces or other characters, less quotes, etc) then previous code should need an adjustment.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q34445384.txt"
FOR /f "tokens=3delims==" %%a IN (
 'findstr /L /c:"add key=\"ReleaseVersion\" value=" "%filename1%"') DO SET "release=%%~a"
ECHO release=%release%

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

I used a file named `q34445384.txt` containing your data for my testing.

Simply find the target string using `findstr` and set the environment variable to the third token using delimiters of `=`, removing the quotes from the value with `~`.

This assumes uniqueness of the target text and that the structure of the line is exactly as posted.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming app.config is valid, well-formed XML, the best way to scrape the release version is to query it via XPath.  You can invoke PowerShell for this.

```js
@echo off
setlocal

set "psCommand=powershell "^
    select-xml \"//add[@key^='ReleaseVersion']\" app.config ^| %%{ $_.node.value };^
""

for /f %%I in ('%psCommand%') do set "version=%%~I"

echo %version%
```

This will parse app.config for a node named "add" which has an attribute named "key" whose value is "ReleaseVersion", then will return that node's "value" attribute's value.  `for /f` captures it to a batch variable.